HEROKU and Micronaut Native Docker Image are incomopatible
My micronaut native docker container is not starting on Heroku after deployment with an error below:

Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT
within 60 seconds of launch

How to fix it?? In the image there is a setting to accept $PORT value

can you add the console output of that app?
